# Error while Importing Events from CSV file to Google Calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar

I was trying to collect the birthdays of my friends in a csv file and trying to create events that repeat yearly so that I could wish them. But when I tried to import that CSV file into Google calendar, I was getting
`Imported 0 out of 0 events. Unable to process your iCal/CSV file.`

I followed [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-correctly-import-events-google-calendar-why-most-out-marc-hammoud/?articleId=6603362274709172224) post for naming the columns in the csv file. Any help is appreciated.
My Google Sheets file: [SheetsLink](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oyOEFJK4QIhNVdC_TZ9PA4D5bl-1vwFlZAnsibhan4Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. While links to external resources might be helpful or required in order to give appropriate attribution, posts here should be self-contained as the links might be unavailable later. Considering this please add a brief summary of the referred source and add a data sample as a table into the question.

Comment: FWIW, the referenced link is [How to correctly import events into Google Calendar, and why most tutorials out there do not work](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-correctly-import-events-google-calendar-why-most-out-marc-hammoud/?articleId=6603362274709172224) on LinkedIn. It provides no more information than Google's own [documentation](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en&visit_id=637759364262144107-1325287020&rd=2#zippy=%2Ccreate-or-edit-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has several flaws:

- By importing by csv directly into Calendar you cannot set reminders, nor can you create a "repeating" event.
- You would have had as much success if you had read and followed the Google documentation ['Import events to Google Calendar' > 'Advanced: Create or edit .csv or iCal files before you import' > 'Create or edit a .csv file'](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en&visit_id=637759364262144107-1325287020&rd=2#zippy=%2Ccreate-or-edit-a-csv-file) as the referenced link
- Krishna Prashanth's Birthday: "Start Date" is not a date value. (test with `ISDATE`)
- Prasaanth's Birthday: "Start Date" is blank

Fix these and you will be able to import direct into Google Calendar **BUT**

- Because every event has an "End Date" of "31/1/2100", every event is shown on EVERY day between the "Start Date" and the "End Date". (refer screenshot).
- Since you are by-passing Google Contacts, you should set an "End Date" equal to the "Start Date", or a day or two after the the "Start Date".

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is there anyway to create an yearly recurring event from the csv file ?

Comment: No (I mentioned this in the first line of the answer). A workaround would be to use Sheets to copy the entries, advance the year (I.e their birthday next year, the year after, etc), and then import multiple annual entries for each person.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, you might consider “accepting” it.

Comment: P.S. have you considered setting up your friends in Google Contacts, and then syncing to Google Calendar?

Comment: I thought of sharing this calendar to my friends too so that they could also be reminded. Hence I thought of creating as a Calendar rather than a Contact as everyone in the list is saved differently in other's contacts.

Comment: Makes sense, and unfortunately the "Birthdays" calendar (which syncs from Contacts) is the only one that can't be shared.